# How to include Ajax request / response for php project

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here's the PHP files in my project. I used a href for *'get movie details'* as per that it goes to another page and shows the results.

```
<a href = "movie_details.php?movie_id=$movie_id" ...
```

I need to get those details with ajax request and render response in same page (better if it in a inside a div).

**table1.php**

```
<?php 
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_selectdb("MovieSite") or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT movie_id, movie_name, movie_director, movie_leadactor FROM Movie ";
            //"WHERE movie_year > 1990 ORDER BY movie_type";

    $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error());

    $num_movies = mysql_num_rows($result);

$movie_header = <<<EOD
        <h2><center>Movie Review Database</center></h2>
        <table width = "70%" border = "1" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "2" align = "center">
            <tr>
                <th>Movie Title</th>
                <th>Movie Director </th>
                <th>Movie Lead Actor</th>
            </tr>       
EOD;

function get_director(){
    global $movie_director;
    global $director;

    $query_d = "SELECT people_fullname FROM people WHERE people_id = '$movie_director'";

    $results_d = mysql_query($query_d) or die(mysql_error());

    $row_d = mysql_fetch_array($results_d);

    extract($row_d);

    $director = $people_fullname;

}

function get_leaderactor(){
    global $movie_leadactor;
    global $leadactor;
    $query_l = "SELECT people_fullname FROM people WHERE people_id = '$movie_leadactor'";

    $result_l = mysql_query($query_l);

    $row_l = mysql_fetch_array($result_l);
    extract($row_l);
    $leadactor = $people_fullname;
}

$movie_details = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $movie_id = $row['movie_id'];
    $movie_name = $row['movie_name'];
    $movie_director = $row['movie_director'];
    $movie_leadactor = $row['movie_leadactor'];

    get_director();
    get_leaderactor();

$movie_details .= <<<EOD
    <tr>
        <td><a href = "movie_details.php?movie_id=$movie_id" title = "Find out more about $movie_name">$movie_name</a></td>
        <td>$director</td>
        <td>$leadactor</td>     
    </tr>
EOD;
}

$movie_details .= <<<EOD

    <tr>
        <td>Total : $num_movies Movies </td>
    </tr>
EOD;

$movie_footer = "</table>";

$movie = <<< MOVIE
    $movie_header;
    $movie_details;
    $movie_footer;
MOVIE;
echo $movie;
?>
```

---

**movie_details.php**

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('MovieSite') or die("DB Select" . mysql_error());

    function calculate_differences($takings, $cost){
        $difference = $takings - $cost;

        if ($difference < 0){
            $difference = substr($difference, 1);
            $font_color = 'red';
            $profit_or_loss = "Rs. " . $difference . "M";           
        }elseif ($difference > 0){
            $font_color = 'green';
            $profit_or_loss = "Rs. " . $difference . "M";
        }else {
            $font_color = 'blue';
            $profit_or_loss = "Broke even";
        }
        return "<font color = \"$font_color\"> ". $profit_or_loss . "</font>"; 
    }

    function get_director(){
        global $movie_director;
        global $director;

        $query_d = "SELECT people_fullname FROM people WHERE people_id = '$movie_director'";

        $results_d = mysql_query($query_d) or die(mysql_error());

        $row_d = mysql_fetch_array($results_d);

        extract($row_d);

        $director = $people_fullname;

    }

    function get_leaderactor(){
        global $movie_leadactor;
        global $leadactor;
        $query_l = "SELECT people_fullname FROM people WHERE people_id = '$movie_leadactor'";

        $result_l = mysql_query($query_l);

        $row_l = mysql_fetch_array($result_l);
        extract($row_l);
        $leadactor = $people_fullname;
    }

    $movie_query = "SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE movie_id = '" . $_GET['movie_id'] . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($movie_query, $link) or die(mysql_error());

$movie_header = <<<EOD
    <h2><center>Movie Review Database</center></h2>

EOD;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //$movie_id = $row['movie_id'];
    $movie_name = $row['movie_name'];
    $movie_director = $row['movie_director'];
    $movie_leadactor = $row['movie_leadactor'];
    $movie_year = $row['movie_year'];
    $movie_running_time = $row['movie_running_time'] . "Mins";
    $movie_takings = $row['movie_taking'];
    $movie_cost = $row['movie_cost'];

    get_director();
    get_leaderactor();
}

$movie_health = calculate_differences($movie_takings, $movie_cost);

$page_start = <<<EOD
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Details and Review for: $movie_name </title>
    </head>
    <body>
EOD;

$movie_table_headings =<<<EOD
<tr>
    <th>Movie Title</th>
    <th>Year of Release</th>
    <th>Movie Director </th>
    <th>Movie Lead Actor</th>
    <th>Movie running Time</th>
    <th>Movie Health</th>
</tr>
EOD;

$movie_details = <<<EOD
<table width = "70%" border = "1" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "2" align = "center">
    <tr>
        <th colspan = "6"><u><h2>$movie_name: details</h2></u></th>
    </tr>
    $movie_table_headings   
    <tr>
        <td width = "33%" align = "center">$movie_name</td>
        <td align = "center">$movie_year</td>
        <td align = "center">$director</td>
        <td align = "center">$leadactor</td>
        <td align = "center">$movie_running_time</td>
        <td align = "center">$movie_health</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
EOD;

$page_end = <<<EOD
    <a href = "table1.php">Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
EOD;

$movie = <<< MOVIE
    $page_start;
    $movie_details;
    $page_end;
MOVIE;
echo $movie;
mysql_close();
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: try asking a question?

Comment: yeah i haven't idea about how to integrate ajax/jquery with php.please help me or give tutorial site for refer

Comment: The jQuery documentation shows how to perform AJAX calls. PHP reads the parameters using `_$GET` or `$_POST`, echoes the output in whatever format you want (JSON is my preference), and the jQuery AJAX function receives this in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX works by allowing you to retrieve the contents of a page using clientside code (e.g. , javascript/jQuery) without making the user leave the current page.

When you make an ajax request, you can specify parameters to send via GET or POST (or not send any parameters at all). Your code will then receive the content of the page as if you had visited it with your browser (what you would get if you went to the page, right-clicked and viewed source).

So what you would want to do with your PHP is to output the values that you need on your current page. It is common practice to encode this data using JSON or XML (which is the X in ajax), so that your clientside code can read it more easily. (I personally prefer JSON).

Learn jQuery: http://w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp
Learn about AJAX: http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
Learn about Ajax with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
  or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
  or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Let me know if that answers your question..